# Layer 2 Encapsulation and Decapsulation in Router

Tags: network, layer3, network-theory

Whenever the router receive a packet from the local network, router will decapsulate the frame to be able access the IP information, after router have done know which interface it will send the data it will encapsulate the packet with a new frame where the source frame is the Mac address of the out interface but how about the destination frame address ? How does the router know the Mac address of the destination interface considering the router doesn't do arp?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the router know the Mac address of the destination interface considering the router doesn't do arp?

For IPv4 over MAC-based networks, ARP is required. IPv6 requires NDP. A router needs to use ARP or NDP to discover the next-hop MAC to use as destination address for the encapsulating frame.

ARP/NDP is not used on network links without (MAC) addressing, such as point-to-point links (serial, PPP, ...).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir